# JavaScript - How to implement a dictionary with keys that aren't strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to do a bit of simple dependency injection in my JavaScript app, so I'd like to write a function that you can pass in a class and it returns you an instance of that class from a list it's got stored.

If I have an array containing a list of tuples (class, instance) it's quite easy to do a linear search for a matching class and return the appropriate instance, but I'd rather implement it as a dictionary type. The problem is that the "key" to the dictionary is of type class (i.e. function) and JavaScript object property names can only be strings.

Is there any way to implement a dictionary with non-string keys in JavaScript, or to write some kind of function that could generate a printable name from a class function?

Comment: You would use a `Map` object for non-string keys, but putting a class function into a Map makes me think there may be a better way to solve your problem.  If you show us the actual problem you're trying to solve (always best to do that here), we can probably offer you an even better solution than putting a class function itself into a map object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Map instead, which can have keys of any type:

```js
class C {
  prop = 'val';
}
const map = new Map();
map.set(C, new C());

console.log(map.get(C));
```

Note that Map lookups and retrievals are done with `.get` and `.set` calls, not with dot/bracket notation like plain objects.

Comment: Worthwhile notice that the classic object-map access via square-brackets is still allowed, but it is NOT what the user expect.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew about this before. I'm a bit surprised they didn't call it "dictionary" or something since "map" already has a meaning in JavaScript.